# setting the result of a sql query as a variable inside an if statement in php

Tags: php, sql

Kind of an unclear question but I'm trying to check if a username has been taken or not.  The code I have now isn't erroring but it's also not working, when echoing the $username variable I get nothing.

```
$sql="SELECT people_username FROM people WHERE people_username='{$_POST['username']}'";

    //Set the result of the query as $username and if the select fails echo an error message
    if ($username = !mysql_query($sql,$con)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    else if ($_POST['username'] == $username){
        $errors[  ] = 'This username is already in use, please try again...sorry';
    }
```

Is it a syntax error or is my logic wrong?

Comment: SQL injection attack risk, pulling direction from `$_POST` - use mysql_escape_real_string.

Comment: I have it filtered earlier with 
$_POST['username'] = filter_var($_POST['username'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

Comment: Try hard coding the $_POST['username'] with a real username to check db connection is up first.

Comment: @Charlie: I wouldn't modify `$_POST['username']` because you'd be 'tainting' a php-supplied variable.  Once you do that, you will never be sure if that variable was posted or supplied through the script.

Comment: This code is in a function, so if I set the post username to another variable I can't get it later when I'm inserting from another function.  so I've kept the sanitized input in the global variable so I can get to it.  Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: I think I answered my own question, I'm going to use the $GLOBALS array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would just do

```
$resource = mysql_query("SELECT people_username FROM people WHERE people_username='".mysql_escape_string($_POST['username'])."'");
if(!$resource) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
} else if(mysql_num_rows($resource) > 0) {
    $errors[  ] = 'This username is already in use, please try again...sorry';
} else {
    //username is not in use... do whatever else you need to do.
}
```

Comment: don't copy and paste that I didn't include mysql_real_escape_string, well I just did.

Answer (score 1):

If some cheeky user happens to try: `'; DROP people; --` as a username, you'd be in big trouble.

You may want to check the following Stack Overflow post for further reading on this topic:

- [What is SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection)

As for the other problem, the other answers already addressed valid solutions. However, make sure to fix the SQL injection vulnerability first. It is never too early for this.

Comment: i think you cant do that anymore. you can extend the select but im prety sure mysql_query just executes 1 query.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong.

It should be something like this:

```
$sql="SELECT people_username FROM people WHERE people_username='".mysql_escape_string($_POST['username'])."'";

//If the select fails echo an error message
if (!($result = mysql_query($sql,$con))) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

if ($data == null){
    $errors[  ] = 'This username is already in use, please try again...sorry';
}
```

Notice that for security reasons you need to escape the strings you use in SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

1. `mysql_query($sql,$con)` returns a resultset (which may be empty)
2. you are not testing any condition with `if($var = !'value')`, you are just assigning a negated resultset to the variable `$username` (what beast that is, I am not sure)

My suggestion: Simplify the code, do not overload lines of code with multiple tasks.
 3. List item

Comment: With ifs we frequently forget to use `==`: so this is wrong `if($a = 3)` because it is an assignment which changes the value of `$a` to `3` and is always true. To check if `$a` is equal to `3` we need `if($a == 3)`